# Bootstrap Carousel Not Scaling, Ends up squishing images, Same Height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Bootstrap Carousel Images are squishing with the same height.  They are not scaling properly.  I have searched and tried several solutions, however, they have not solved my problem.  Here is my html.

I tried adding adding links to several different css files.  I also tried adding several links to different js files.  I tried to change the height from 500px to auto.  I tried changing min-width 100% to width 100%.

I am using Bootstrap 3.0, however most of the solutions refer to earlier versions.  The solutions that referred to 3.0 did not work.  I just started learning BS.  I have a good working knowledge of html and css.  I believe that this has to do with js, but I cannot figure out my specific issue.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="mywebsite.com, Web and Media." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="web design, web development, media, talent, marketing, " />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="INDEX, FOLLOW" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    
    <title>Blackhock | Web &amp; Media</title>    

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'analytics#']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My website</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></span></li>
            <li><a href="#free-quote">Get a Free Quote!</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Info<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

        <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/slider1.jpg" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Web &bull; Media</h1>
              <p></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#free-quote" role="button">Get A Free Quote!</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/slider1.jpg" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Web</h1>
              <p>Website Design &amp; Development, Responsive Layouts, Search Engine Optimization...</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/slider1.jpg" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Media</h1>
              <p>Graphic Design, Logos, Web Banners...</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/slider1.jpg" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Entrepreneurs</h1>
              <p>Make your dreams a reality!</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- 
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
      -->
    </div>    

    <!-- /.carousel -->

    <hr class="layout">

        <!-- Marketing messaging
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">

      <h2 class="text-center line-divider">My website</h2>

      <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <img src="images/pc.png" width="140" height="140" alt="pc image">
          <h2 id="free-quote">Web</h2>
          <p>Website Design &amp; Development, Responsive Layouts, Search Engine Optimization...</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">More Info &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="images/media.jpg" width="140" height="140" alt="media image">
          <h2>Media</h2>
          <p>Graphic Design, Logos, Web Banners...</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">More Info &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="images/entrepreneurs.jpg" width="140" height="140" alt="entrepreneurs image">
          <h2>Entrepreneurs</h2>
          <p>Do you have an idea that will change the world?  It all starts with the first step.  We can help make your dreams a reality!</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">More Info &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        &copy;2014 My Website&trade; All Rights Reserved
      </div>
    </footer>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the custom css that I have added.

```
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you include bootstrap js 3 times? Include it just once!

Comment: @Sebsemillia, I didn't know they were the same.  I just removed <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> and nothing changed.  What other js should I remove?